# creating multiple functions in one activity android application

Tags: java, android, xml

Question 1:
I have 2 activities. I was wondering how to optimize it. I can either create 2 activities with multiple listeners. Or create multiple java files for each button(onclick listener)
Question 2: I have tried to create multiple listeners in one java but can only get one button to work. What is the syntax for multiple listeners in one java file? Here is my *updated code:
now the issue is no matter what button is clicked on it leads to the same page. I think the problem is indicated in the text within these brackets [-{}-]
activity1.java

```
package install.fineline;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class Activity1 extends Activity {

Button Button1;
Button Button2;
Button Button3;
Button Button4;
Button Button5;
Button Button6;
[-{
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.fineline);
addListenerOnButton();
}
}-]

public void addListenerOnButton() {

final Context context = this;

Button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.autobody);

Button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);   

    }

});

Button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.glass);

Button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);   

    }

});

Button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wheels);

Button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);   

    }

});

Button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.speedy);

Button4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);   

    }

});

Button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sevan);

Button5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);   

    }

});
```

Button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.towing);

Button6.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);   

}

});

}}

activity2.java

package install.fineline;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Activity2 extends Activity {

Button button1;

public void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.autobody);
}
Button button2;

public void onCreate2(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.glass);
}
Button button3;

public void onCreate3(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.wheels);
}
Button button4;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.speedy);
}
Button button5;

public void onCreate5(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.sevan);
}

Button button6;

public void onCreate6(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.towing);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were definitely on the right way with your answer. But `onCreate1`, `onCreate2`, etcetera will never be called. Instead, try this:

```
package install.fineline;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class Activity1 extends Activity {

Button button1;
Button button2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fineline);
    addListenerOnButton();
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    final Context context = this;

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.autobody);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AutoBodyActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);   

        }

    });

    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.glass);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, GlassActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);   
    }
});
}
```

And make a seperate `Activity` for each layout you wanna bring up (notice that in the code above I reference `AutoBodyActivity` and `GlassActivity` instead of `Activity2`):

```
package install.fineline;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class AutoBodyActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.autobody);
    }
}
```

and:

```
package install.fineline;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class GlassActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.glass);
    }
}
```

It adds separate listeners to the seperate buttons uppon creating the `Activity`. The `onCreate()` method will automatically be called when the `Activity` is created, but the `onCreate1()` method was never called.

I think you should have a look at some [basic Java tutorials](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_syntax.htm) to understand more of the syntax and after that go trough the [Android tutorials](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html). This will help you understand why the code in your `Activity2` did not work the way you thought it should work and give you a better sense of how to handle seperate activities. No offence :) we are all learning.

I hope my answer helped you.

Comment: I see why. Please have a look at my updated/edited answer to see how it can work.